# How to encode raw bytes?

Tags: google-chrome, byte, barcode-scanner, datamatrix

We have a 2D datamatrix barcode which outputs as 12002052 (CR+LF after the value).  When scanning into Chrome the barcode is triggering the downloads menu - which I have read from other posts that this is due to the CR+LF.  To troubleshoot, we generated a new 2D datamatrix barcode with an online generator for 12002052 which scans successfully in Chrome (doesn't trigger the downloads menu) but when scanned into notepad++ (showing all characters) it shows the exact same output as the original/bad barcode.

I took an image of both the good and bad barcode and uploaded them to a datamatrix decoding website (zxing) and what is interesting is the last value in the "raw bytes" is different for each barcode

bad 2D

```
Raw text                12002052
Raw bytes               8e 82 96 b6 81 
Barcode format          DATA_MATRIX
Parsed Result Type      TEXT
Parsed Result           12002052
```

good 2D

```
Raw text                12002052
Raw bytes               8e 82 96 b6 0b
Barcode format          DATA_MATRIX
Parsed Result Type      TEXT
Parsed Result           12002052
```

my question is what exactly are the "raw bytes" and how could I possible encode them to hopefully reverse engineer this and find what is differentiating the 2 barcodes?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that 'Raw bytes' would refer to a byte array. Byte arrays are exactly what they sound like, an array of bytes which are 8 bits each. So, the raw bytes '8e 82 96 b6 0b' refer to hexidecimal representations of each byte.

That said, from the string you have provided - I do not get a corresponding byte array that matches the raw text input provided. (There are plenty of string to byte converters online) Perhaps some character encoding other than ASCII or UTF8 is used in this case.

Comment: that's the frustrating part, I thought it was hex too but I am not getting any matches with online converters either

Comment: While I don't have a solution to your question, I do believe the issue to be the encoding of the string. You might find this link relevant https://github.com/zxing/zxing/issues/365